# Cannot load model in CI 2.1. Gives 500 internal server error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've recently upgraded to CodeIgniter 2.1 and I cannot load a model. This is killing me. I know its something silly, still can't figure it out. Can someone please tell me where I'm making the mistake? Thanks

MY CONTROLLER -> site.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

    public function test()
    {
        $this->load->model('site_model')
        $info['rows'] = $this->site_model->getInfo();
        $this->load->view('test_view',$info);
    }
}
```

MY Model -> site_model.php

```
<?php
class Site_model extends CI_Model {

    public function getInfo() {

        $q = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM dmart_product');

        if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data_info[] = $row;
            }
            return $data_info;
        }       

    }



}
```

My view -> test_view.php : Contains nothing but HTML codes.

Still ists giving me **"500 Internal Server Error"**

Any Ideas? Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: P.S: I've autoloaded the database.

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` on your site?

Comment: Yes I do James. I think the problem is solved. I'll update in a few minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is 'missing semi-colon' on the line loading model

Comment: Goodness!! How could I end up doing that?? thanks a lot Kidonchu! Wish I had 15 rep to vote you up. Really appreciate!

Comment: No Problem. I recommend using any kind of editor that has syntax error highlighting feature. It helps a lot saving time spent on this kind of small errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need add __construct() method in Site_model
Like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Winston, but it doesn't help. I've tried it already. Also, I've autoloaded the database.

Comment: Also, isn't it optional since extending CI_Model automatically constructs? Thanks